# img disappearing and media query navbar rearranging

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries, navbar

HTML

```
<body>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <div id="img">
                <img src="images/pfp.jpg" alt="pfp">
            </div>
            <div id="name">
                <a>Noah Stone</a>
            </div>
            <div id="links">
                <a id="exp">Experience</a>
                <a id="contact">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <h1 id="intro">Hello, World!</h1>
        <p id="desc">I'm an aspiring Front-end developer enthusiast based in Northwest Arkansas,<br>
         with a keen interest in honing my skills and gaining real-world experience.</p>
    </body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #B9B4C7;
    margin: 0;
}
#img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 6em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    order: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
#img img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#navbar {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    /* border: dotted; */
    display: flex;
    height: 6em;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#name {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    order: 2;
}
#links {
    font-size: large;
    margin: 1.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    order: 3;
}
nav a {
    /* border: dotted; */
    color: #FAF0E6;
    font-size: larger;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#exp {
    margin: 1em;
}
#contact {
    background-color: #352F44;
    padding: .5em;
}
#intro {
   /* border: dotted; */
    color: #352F44;
    font-size: 8em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#desc {
    /* border: dotted; */
    color: #5C5470;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 638px) {

    #navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }
    
    #name {
        order: 1;
        margin-left: .5em;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    }

    #links {
        order: 2;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #img {
        order: 3;
        height: 10em;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

I'm using a media query to change the navbar layout. My desired look if for the #name to be top left, #contact directly underneath and the #exp to the right of #contact. Then I want the placeholder img a little bigger and on the right side, but every time I try to change it it disappears. The name and links are fine just wanting the #contact closest to the left.